# Imagick PHP Thumbnail From Large Image "Caught exception: Invalid image geometryn"

Tags: php, imagick

I am trying to create a thumbnail from large images (20,000px x 20,000px or more), but I keep getting "Caught exception: Invalid image geometryn". I've tried finding a solution and nothing works for me yet. I can't seem to change policy.xml because I am on shared hosting and can't find it. Here is the code that I used in attempts to leverage disk caching and run the thumbnail method.

```
$file = "uploads/rawfile.jpg";

try {
    $img = new Imagick($file);
    $img->setResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MEMORY, 256);
    $img->setResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MAP, 256);
    $img->setResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_AREA, 1512);
    $img->setResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_FILE, 768);
    $img->setResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_DISK, -1);
    $img->thumbnailImage(1200, 0, TRUE);
    $img->writeImage('thumbnails/ok.jpg');
    $img->clear();
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "n";
}
```

Comment: See the log file from the server as it might help you find out the real problem

Comment: @Pratansyah The actual error is "Caught exception: Invalid image geometryn"

Comment: Well there's the problem. You're passing 0 in `$img->thumbnailImage(1200, 0, TRUE)`

Comment: @Pratansyah The 0 is to maintain aspect ratio. Even when I change it to something like 800 for instance, I go back to the error 500. The error log (on my shared hosting) doesn't get updated in this instance in order to show me where the issue is - at least not the error log in the same directory as my PHP file - trying to find it.

Comment: You might want to disable the error 500 page on your site for debugging purpose so you don't have to go back and forth looking at your log file